# From string parameter to color in java awt

Tags: java, string, colors, awt

I want to set a color for a `Polygon` by my String parameter. Here's my code:

```
public void polygon(int xPoints[], int yPoints[], int nPoints, String col) {
    this.graphics.setColor(col);
    this.graphics.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);

}
```

This is not working. So, after some research I tried to add in my code  `Color c = c.web(col);`
and this also is not working. How can I transform the String `col` to `color`?

Comment: Can you give example input for `col` parameter?

Comment: Yes.for example "red"

Comment: Try color.RED it will help

Comment: Aside from main question, why do you even have `this.graphics`? When is that field initialized?

Comment: thanks.I'm using this because the "public void polygon" is in a class which draws some 2D graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following:

```
// Fill the map with colors you required
static Map<String, Color> colorMap = Map.ofEntries(Map.entry("RED", Color.RED),
        Map.entry("BLUE", Color.BLUE),
        Map.entry( "BLACK", Color.BLACK),
        Map.entry( "ORANGE", Color.ORANGE));

static Color getColor(String col)
{
        return colorMap.get(col.toUpperCase());
}

public void polygon(int xPoints[], int yPoints[], int nPoints, String col)
{
    this.graphics.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
    this.graphics.setColor( getColor(col) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The setColor method doesn't take a String as a parameter. It takes java.awt.Color. Try this instead:

```
// add the proper import

import java.awt.Color;

// substitute this line

this.graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
```

If your determined to use a String, you're going to have to use a mapping. Hash your String as key and return the corresponding Color constant as a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you cannot use `java.awt.Color` directly, as in `Color.red` and `Color.blue`, you can use reflection to get the corresponding Color from the color name, as in the following method.

```
Color getColorFromString( String colorStr ) {
    Color color = null;
    try {
        Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField(colorStr);
        color = (Color)field.get(null);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        // Handle Invalid color
    }
    return color;
}
```

Alternative, you could have a prefilled `static Map<String, Color>` having the colour string as key, and the corresponding Color object as value.